# Bash script to analyze directory and print directory summary

Tags: bash, unix

I am working on a script that will analyze any dir in unix and will display the output:
**script.sh dir1 dir2 ... dirn**

**Needed output:**
Directory xxx contains yy files and zz directories

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter Dir names'
read dirs
for input_source in $dirs; do 
ls -ld|wc -l; 
echo
# here goes a problem I am trying to figure out how to get this value printed by echo
# together with dirs and files quantity
```

Please advise.

I am not able to figure out how to proceed with the code. Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note: Edited to take care of new line in file/dir names.**

Better not to parse `ls` command's output.

To count files (no dirs):

```
find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo -n . \; | wc -c
```

To count dirs:

```
find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo -n . \; | wc -c
```

Your full script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter Dir names'
read dirs
for DIR in "$dirs"; do 
    numFiles=$(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo -n . \; | wc -c)
    numDirs=$(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo -n . \; | wc -c)
    echo "Directory $DIR contains $numFiles files and $numDirs directories"
done
```

Comment: Using `find $DIR ... | wc -l` has exactly the same problem as parsing `ls`.  If a filename contains a newline, the count will be off.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Thanks, that was a valid point. I edited my answer to take care of it now.

Answer (score 1):

in your code use the following : @where ls -ld is written

getting directories

```
  ls -latr | sed -n '/^d/p' zdirlst | grep -v "\."
```

getting files :

```
  ls -latr | sed -n '/^-/p' zdirlst | grep -v "\."
```

add wc -l to get count and display as per reqd ...

hope this helps !!