# Reuse or repeat pipe input as arguments in command (example given)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'll explain this problem with an example. Let's say I want to generate a list with two columns. Column 1 contains a file name and column 2 contains the md5 sum of that file.

This can be done using the following script:

```
for FILE in `ls -p | grep -v "/"`;
do
    printf "%s %s\n" "$FILE" `md5 -q "$FILE"`;
done;
```

Can this be done on a single line using pipes? I've tried using different combinations of `sed`, `xargs` and `printf` but I think I'm missing something. Here's one of my attempts:

```
ls -p | grep -v "/" | xargs -I FILE printf "%s %s\n" FILE `md5 -q FILE`
```

In that attempt, the `FILE` inside the backticks isn't substituted, which isn't really surprising.

Is this the kind of thing where I should just use a multi-line script? Since there's no logic or control flow, I feel that a one-liner should be possible and that perhaps I'm not using my tools properly or I haven't found the right tool.

Apologies for the title, I have no idea what to call this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `md5sum`, because I don't have `md5` :)

```
ls -p | grep -v / | xargs md5sum | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

and this may be a safer, more robust way:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | awk '{s=$2; $2=$1; $1=s;}1'
```

this should work with md5:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sed 's/[^(]*(\([^)]*\)) =/\1/'
```

Comment: FYI: Example output from `/sbin/md5` on Mac OS X: `MD5 (install.sh) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`.  Yours is the general approach I'd take; given the need to strip parentheses, I'd probably use `sed` rather than `awk` (though `awk` can be made to do what's necessary).

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
ls *.cc | xargs -I FILE md5 FILE | sed 's/^MD5 (\(.*\)) =/\1/'
```

Or if you're worried about spaces in your filenames (which I don't think you should allow yourself in any case),

```
find . -name "*.cc" -maxdepth 1 | xargs -I FILE md5 FILE | sed 's/^MD5 (\(.*\)) =/\1/'
```

Comment: @anubhava: But spaces, tabs, newlines should all be discouraged in filenames...like Beta said...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes I agree it should be discouraged but still these filenames are supported in all Unix flavors and it would be nice if a suggested command can work with those names as well.

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, it would be nice...you can't use `ls`, and you probably end up using `find` or maybe shell globbing, and you still have problems with a file name such as `abc) = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nMD5 (` where the '`aaa`' is a valid MD5 hex string and the `\n` is a newline embedded in the file name.  This makes it look as though there were two files being MD5-hashed.  Disambiguating that sort of output is hard!  A lot depends on the context.  If you have to deal with what anyone might do, you have to worry about newlines etc.  If it is for your own use, you can decide you don't have to.

Comment: @anubhava: I'm almost proud to say I didn't think of anything as pathological as file names with newline characters in them. But you're right, this is not a robust solution; perreal's is more robust and tidier.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I my self upvoted both the answers btw even perreal's answer didn't work with filenames with newline character. @@JonathanLeffler I totally agree with context part. If we're not dealing with those funky filenames why complicate the command. (btw I commented as [my answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953793/bash-script-to-analyze-directory-and-print-directory-summary/16953883#16953883) were also subjected to this requirement :P)

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -p | grep -v "/" | xargs -I FILE sh -c 'printf "%s %s\n" $0 `md5 -q $0`' FILE
```

Your code wasn't working because the backticks are processed by the original shell before passing the arguments to `xargs`. You need to protect them from processing by enclosing them in quotes, and then passing that argument to `sh`.

However, this seems like a bad way to do it. It doesn't work for files with spaces in the names, and `grep` is a silly way to skip directories.

```
for FILE in *
do
  if  [ -f "$FILE" ]
  then printf "%s %s\n" "$FILE" `md5 -q "$FILE"`
done
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't consider calling sh and using $0 as a placeholder for the argument, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To take care of concerns regarding file names with weird characters in the name, that require escaping, **EXCEPT** `"` character, or file names with md5 sums and spaces as part of their names:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  -print0 |xargs -0 -n1 -I{} bash -c 'echo -n "{} " ; cat "{}" |md5sum' | sed 's/ -$//'
```

Using `cat` makes the filename for `md5sum` the standard input (`-`) which we strip off with `sed`. However, no complex regexps required to change the order of the columns, as we use `echo -n` to print the filename as the first column of the output.

Example:

```
samveen@precise:/tmp/tmp.JpmDNkhcRG$ touch "ab'c"
samveen@precise:/tmp/tmp.JpmDNkhcRG$ touch "ab d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e c"
samveen@precise:/tmp/tmp.JpmDNkhcRG$ touch "ab c"
samveen@precise:/tmp/tmp.JpmDNkhcRG$ touch "abc"
samveen@precise:/tmp/tmp.JpmDNkhcRG$ touch "ab
> c"
samveen@precise:/tmp/tmp.JpmDNkhcRG$ touch "ab\!c"

samveen@precise:/tmp/tmp.JpmDNkhcRG$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  -print0 |xargs -0 -n1 -I{} bash -c 'echo -n "{} " ; cat "{}" |md5sum'| sed 's/ -$//'
./ab'c d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./ab d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e c d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./ab c d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./abc d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./ab
c d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./ab\!c d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```